# Refresh a Classic Report

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to refresh a classic report with this code and it works fine putting it in `Function and Global Variable Declaration` and calling the function in `Execute when Page Loads`

`var doIt = function(){
 $('#P_REPORT').trigger('apexrefresh');
  setTimeout("doIt()", 5000);
}`

but when i add to that page a modalfrom with jquery it stop working and i can't why.

The application page is here http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=40263:5
Workspace: WORK_DEV
Username: user
Password: 123qweasd

if someone could help me I would appreciate

Tanks

Comment: I've taken a look at your app but can't see what is wrong. I thought you meant your timer stopped working, but it doesn't. I added a small piece of code in your doIt() function which adds a div each time it is called. When you open or close the modalform, it just keeps going. What exactly is going wrong for you?

Comment: if you remove the JavaScript code of the modalform the refresh starts working but with that code it doesn't refresh the report. I put the sysdate there so i can see the report refreshing and the time is stoped. And yes its right the code you put in the function but doesnt refresh the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html header you define the following scripts:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
```

I believe you get some jquery conflict issues with these, as apex already includes the jquery files by default! (when you view your page source you can verify this)

```
<script src="/i/javascript/apex_4_1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When you remove the references to your jquery files, your report refreshes correctly again.

If you want to use your own libraries, it might be best to alter your page template so it doesnt include the standard libraries, but does your own.

Alternatively, maybe it is possible to define the jquery var ($) through some voodo, like [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) - though i wouldn't know how.

Comment: Is there a way to use mine insted of apex one?